# fail2ban - have more than one regex in same filter file

Tags: fail2ban

I have the following in my `fail2ban/filter.d/apache-scripts.conf file`:

```
[INCLUDES] before = botsearch-common.conf

[Definition]

failregex = (<HOST>).*(GET|HEAD|POST|PUT)\ \/(site\/|blog\/|old\/|new\/|web\/|dev\/).* 
            (<HOST>).*GET\ \/(phpmyadmin|phpmanager|[pP][hH][pP][mM][yY][aA][dD][mM][iI][nN]).*
            (<HOST>).*\"GoScraper\"$

ignoreregex = 192\.168\.3\.[0-9]{1,2}\ (myhostname\.com|192.168.1.1)
```

So - can I have multiple `failregex` in the same filter.d file? I can't find anything online if I can have multiple regex and if this is the correct format..

Answer (score 4):

https://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/MANUAL_0_8#Configuration

The documentation URL is for v0.8, but the syntax has not significantly changed. The short answer is 'yes', you can place more than one regex per line and the software will try to match them one at a time to the logs.